# How can I avoid a low-cardinality partition key in Cassandra?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, schema

If I'm storing product data for multiple merchants in Cassandra, and I'd like to be able to retrieve an individual product or all products for a merchant, how can I avoid a low-cardinality partition key on that table? For example,

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (
    merchant_id uuid,
    product_id text,
    description text,

    PRIMARY KEY (merchant_id, product_id)
);
```

As far as I understand it, that works, but it has the problem that if I have a small number of merchants (dozens, say) and a large number of products (millions), the data won't be very well distributed across nodes.

The workaround I've come up with is this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id text,
    merchant_id uuid,
    description text,

    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON products (merchant_id);
```

In this case, the product ID has the merchant ID prepended to it to make it unique. This seems hacky. I'm also concerned that a lookup in the secondary index will return millions of primary keys.

What is the correct thing to do here? I'm quite early in development, so I'm open to significant schema changes if necessary, and I'd like to do things the Right Way for Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a composite partition key. If you can sort all the products into **category** and there is enough categories (thousands) then you can create a `PRIMARY KEY((merchand_id, category), product_id)`

Otherwise, what is your read pattern ?

Your original design `PRIMARY KEY((merchand_id), product_id)` seems to imply that you want to list **all** products by merchand, is it a necessary business requirement ?

If not, you can just as well use `PRIMARY KEY(product_id)`

Comment: Yes, that's right -- the read pattern for that table is to read all of the products for a merchant (to create a feed).